# push notification using Django

Tags: python, django, push-notification, push

I am very new to Django and am looking into research and development for a project that will push my availability and rates for a given resort to a list of subscribed clients based on the resort IDs that they have chosen to subscribe to. I know this is possible with sql server and windows services but how is something like this (if possible) done in django? can the CMS handle configuration for all this?
I saw this: [Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

but not sure where to look in here for what I am after.

Anybody have experience with push notifications via django? would be grateful for any pointers

I see alot of questions for pushing to android system and iphone but I just want a simple push to a given url.

Comment: You could provide them with a RSS feed (Tastypie can do this) that they would poll from time to time. For proper "pushing" you would simply hook the save() method of a desired model and every time it gets called you inform the clients it has changed. For Android and iPhone this starts to get tricky as you will need a developer account with an application ID and all the good stuff in order to use their push services.

Comment: Hi @LaurentJalbertSimard when you say hook?

Comment: Have a look into the _Signals_ topic on the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).
`@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    ...`

Comment: @LaurentJalbertSimard would you please put this as an answer so that I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into the Signals topic on the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel) 
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs): 
    ...
```